# Apple HTTP LIVE streaming

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming

Is it possible to use the Live streaming method to create a Voice call or Video call app ?
thanks

Comment: The [HTTP Live Streaming](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-05) protocol from Apple is not designed for two way live communication. If you update the index file fast enough it would come close, but note that it would require a server on each side publishing the files to stream. It's just not the appropriate technology for the job.

Answer (score 4):

HLS is not the ideal technology for your purpose due to

1. **Latency** HLS video stream is broken down into mpegts chunks of 10secs each which has to be transferred fully before it can be played. Hence there is always a significant delay associated with HLS.
2. **Buffering** In case of poor data transmission, HLS player buffers and doesn't skip ahead which is not what you want for a video chat.
3. **No Hole punching** HLS works on HTTP, not UDP - so you won't be able to leverage [UDP hole-punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) if your clients are behind NAT / firewalls